# looping over large csv python

Tags: python

I have a large csv-file(several hundreds of lines) containing following structure:
*filename, sitename, servername*

this csv-file contains several doubles, since the servernames are those from a cluster(always the same couples) and language-aliases for the sitenames(eg. mijnhuis, myhouse, mamaison)

the result I'd like to have is the following(notice the ; and the , :
*filename; sitename1, sitename2, sitename3; servername1, servername2, servername3;*

How could I do this in the most optimized way?

PS: actual code would be nice, but if you can give me directions, I'd be equally happy.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: "large csv-file(several hundreds of lines)" - not exactly large, so I wouldn't have thought at this stage any optimisation is required whatsoever

Comment: wow: just because I haven't posted anything means I haven't tried...

Answer (score 3):

Use at your own risk:

```
import collections as c

f = open('input', 'r')
sites, servers = c.defaultdict(set), c.defaultdict(set)
files = set()
for line in f:
    parts = line.split(',')
    fi,site,server = [p.strip() for p in parts]
    files.add(fi)
    sites[fi].add(site)
    servers[fi].add(server)

for f in files:
    print "%s; %s; %s" % (f, ", ".join(sites[f]), ", ".join(servers[f]))
```

Comment: It's simpler and commonly expected to use `from collections import defaultdict`

Comment: @Jon... it's a habit :) I'm generally not a huge fan of from x import y. I like to immediately see that something is imported. Although in cases like this I'd agree that it's a little overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure depends on your program.  Perhaps you could also store
a dictionary of filenames to a list of tuples `(sitename1, servname2)`  THere are tons of ways to accomplish what you are tryign to do

You could do something like:

```
import csv

file_names_to_data = {}

with open('your_csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   for line_list in reader:
      try:      
        file_names_to_data[line_list[0]]['sitenames'].append(line_list[1])
        file_names_to_data[line_list[0]]['servernames'].append(line_list[2])
      except KeyError:
        # initialize it
        file_names_to_data[line_list[0]] = {'sitenames': [line_list[1]], 'servernames': [line_list[2]]}
```

ADditionally it looks like [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) could be extremely usedful.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary for filename and 2 lists of sitenames and servernames for each dictionary item

Answer (score 0):

as it so happens, here included, a solution for my problem. exampleFile included.

CODE:

```
fp = r'PATH_TO_FILE'

aliases = []
aliases.append(("sitex","sitez","sitey"))


splitFile = []
for l in open(fp):
    parts = tuple(l[:-1].replace(" ","").split(","))
    splitFile.append(parts)

def isAlias(old, new):
    print old, new
    aliasFound = False
    for alias in aliases:
        if old in alias and new in alias:
            aliasFound = True

    return aliasFound

handledSites = []
for split in splitFile:
    log = split[0]
    site = split[1]
    rp = split[2]


    matchFound = False
    for hs in handledSites:
        if site in hs[0]:
            matchFound = True
            if rp not in hs[1]:
                hs[1].append(rp)
            if log not in hs[2]:
                hs[2].append(log)
        if not matchFound:
            if isAlias(hs[0][0], site):
                matchFound = True
                hs[0].append(site)
                if rp not in hs[1]:
                    hs[1].append(rp)
                if log not in hs[2]:
                    hs[2].append(log)
    if not matchFound:
        handledSites.append(([site],[rp],[log]))

for s in handledSites:
    print s
```

EXAMPLE FILE

```
logfile[date]_[server]_sitex.log, sitex, rp1
logfile[date]_[server]_sitex.log, sitex, rp2
logfile[date]_[server]_sitey.log, sitey, rp1
logfile[date]_[server]_sitey.log, sitey, rp2
logfile[date]_[server]_sitez.log, sitez, rp1
logfile[date]_[server]_sitez.log, sitez, rp2
logfile[date]_[server]_site3.log, site3, rp1
logfile[date]_[server]_site3.log, site3, rp2
```